# Is it possible to perform evelope encryption in CockroachDB?

Tags: encryption, encryption-asymmetric, cockroachdb, envelope, cockroachcloud

With Tink and AEAD I can perform envelope encryption in BigQuery.  ref:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#enveloping
https://fuchsia.googlesource.com/third_party/tink/+/refs/tags/v1.4.0/docs/KEY-MANAGEMENT.md#envelope-encryption

In CockroachDB there is an encrypt and encrypt_iv functions but I can't find away to protect the DEK with a KEK stored in a cloud KMS.  Is this possible ?

I have read the CockroachDB documentation and also looked into the CockroachDB source code but can not find any help.

Answer (score 0):

Customer-Managed Encryption Keys (CMEK) might be the functionality that you are looking for: https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/cmek

Comment: hi - I was thinking more data centric, CMEK and KMS is really just disk or file encryptioin.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: @DanClift It's a little indirect, but ultimately, CMEK does lead to direct encryption of the data, explained [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/cockroachcloud/cmek#how-cmek-works). Enabling CMEK will enable direct data encryption in CRDB, with a DEK + KEK. A CMEK key provided through a cloud KMS is used to encrypt/decrypt KEK. It's one more layer than the question asks ("protect the DEK with a KEK stored in a cloud KMS"); DEK is protected with a KEK which is further protected by a cloud KMS key managed by customer. But ultimately CMEK leads to data encryption through a DEK. (c.r. @ding)